# Flask website capture image from phone camera refreshing page/session and does not upload

Tags: python, html, flask

I am running a flask website and one of my pages had a file input that is set to capture from mobile camera. For some reason after I capture an image and confirm it, the page refreshes and the image is not in the file input. Some times the it will bring the user back to the login page since all my pages have @login_required I assume it is clearing the session data. This also only happens on some phones, S20FE doesnt work, IPhone 10 works, Note 10 works (half the time), pixel 3 works.

I have tried it on chrome, firefox and safari. Both in regular and private browsing. I am not sure if its my HTML or my flask backend or is this a hardware issue. Choosing a file does works fine but capturing an image directly does not.

Flask test page

```
@app.route('/test')
def newtest():
    return render_template("testing/upload_raw.html")

@app.route('/test', methods=["POST"])
def newpost():
    print ("POST")
```

Imports

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
import requests
import json
from datetime import timedelta
from functools import wraps
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from time import sleep
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

HTML snippet

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="input-group feild">
                <span class="material-icons back icon">add_a_photo</span>
                <b><p class="back inputFeild" style="color:#333; width: 60px">Upload</p></b><br>
                <input type="file" name="image"  id="inputGroupFile04" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
            </div>
            <b><input style="width:140px;" id=submit class="w3-button w3-deep-green" type="submit" value="Submit"></b>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After a period of testing, it all works fine every time, then the next day it breaks again.
Website hosted on pythonanywhere.
Using HTTPS